# Listview onItemClickListener in fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
    public class Titles extends Fragment {
    View view;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       MySqlite db=new MySqlite(getActivity());
       view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);
       ListView list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
       Cursor all_titles = db.getTitle();
       adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.fragment_titles,
                all_titles,
                new String[] { db.KEY_TITLE},
                new int[] { R.id.tv_title }, 0);
        //Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"ListView Clicked Go Ahead",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
               String selected_title=tv.getText().toString();

               // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
               Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Poem.class);
               // sending data to new activity
               i.putExtra("title", selected_title);
               startActivity(i);

           }
       });

     return view;

    }
}
```

I'm just beginning Android development, and I'm working to get a Custom listview with a checkbox working.I'm having problems clicking on ListView items in the fragments. In emulator the listview click event is not working. Am using fragment. 
Can any one please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I edited some parts of your code. The whole code is bellow:

```
public class Titles extends Fragment {

  View view;
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);

  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

      View view = getView();

      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      MySqlite db = new MySqlite(getActivity());

      ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

      Cursor all_titles = db.getTitle();

      adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
              R.layout.fragment_titles,
              all_titles,
              new String[] { db.KEY_TITLE},
              new int[] { R.id.tv_title }, 0);

      //Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
      list.setAdapter(adapter);

      list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"ListView Clicked Go Ahead",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
             String selected_title=tv.getText().toString();

             // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
             Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Poem.class);
             // sending data to new activity
             i.putExtra("title", selected_title);
             getActivity().startActivity(i);

         }

      });

      return view;

  }

}
```

Basically, I've only moved your code to `onActivityCreated` and changed this part `startActivity(i)` to this `getActivity().startActivity(i)`.